# Get Parent "li" text using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
jQuery(".hm_filter_middle-category-container [role=listbox] li").on("click", function () {
        selected_category = jQuery(this).text().replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
        parent_selected_category = jQuery(this).closest('ul').closest('li');
    console.log(parent_selected_category);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hm_filter_middle-category-list_wrapper">
   <li data-accordion-id="12" data-auto-select="true" class="accordionItemController">Dresses<span>(1566)</span></li>
   <div id="accordionContent_12" class="hm_filter_middle-category-list sub-category2 accordionItem">
      <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
         <li data-value="Mini" data-id="12" tabindex="-1" role="option"  aria-selected="false">Mini<span>(1566)</span></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get parent li id of this,

Expected value on click the "Mini" in below code would be
"**Dresses**".

Any thoughts, how to get it on click the "**Mini**" Li ?

code i tried added in snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//if i understood your question correctly you need like this


  $("[data-id]").click(function(){
          var id = $(this).parents(".hm_filter_middle-category-list_wrapper").find('.accordionItemController').attr("data-accordion-id")
        })
```

or

if it is not dynamic or the li is always before the accorionContent_12 like this:

```
   $("[data-id]").click(function(){
              var id = $(this).parents("#accordionContent_12").prev().attr("data-accordion-id")
            })
```

Comment: console.log(jQuery(this).parents(".hm_filter_middle-category-list_wrapper").find('.accordionItemController').text()); works but how to remove "(1566)" from Dresses<span>(1566) ?

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: oh for remove just add .find("span").remove()

Comment: actually, i just want to remove it from the value not the html.